# Magento: Get Image Gallery in list.phtml

Tags: magento

How can I grab the image gallery into the category page in Magento, for a loaded product?

```
this->getImageGallery($_product)
```

, won't work..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());

foreach ($product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) {
    echo var_export($image->getUrl());
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to get url of resized image using above code ?

Comment: @Anand you do <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image', $image->getFile())->resize(163, 100); ?>" alt="" />

Comment: Just one side note. The `getMediaGalleryImages()` method returns only the enabled images.

Comment: this solution adds a significant load to the page is list is long.

Comment: Because it loads each full product item, it does add about 500ms to our TTFB for the catalog pages (64gb ram 3.9ghz 8core server) any other ideas?

Comment: @RickyOdinMatthews i want to call only two images of the product on mouseover and onmouseout. what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another method which doesn't require loading the entire product object.

```
<?php $media_gallery = $_product->getMediaGallery(); ?>
<?php foreach ($media_gallery['images'] as $_image):?>
    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image', $_image['file'])->resize(135); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_image['label']) ?>" />
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: To get this to work on list.phtml, I had to add the code; `$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('media_gallery')->getBackend()->afterLoad($_product);`