# Magento display multiple product images on details page

Tags: magento

I am uploading 2 images for each product. Only 2 no more, no less.
[image: Product Images]

1st image is product base image and will be displayed on product details page.

I am using following line to display this image:

```
$_img = '<img src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(180, 300).'" alt="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'" title="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'" />';
                echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_img, 'image');
```

I am able to display the above image correctly.

Second image will be displayed in a pop up when a particular link is clicked. I do not want to display a gallery. Just want to display each image separately.

I think I found a way to retrieve array of images uploaded:

```
$productData = $_product->getData();
$secondImage = $productData['media_gallery']['images'][1];
```

Now, I am not sure how to display this image. I mean how to use helper, like I used for first image to make is display second image. 
I've option to hardcode the complete path of image and use:

```
$secondImage['file'];
```

to display the image etc, but, I want to know if there is way, I can do it magento way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>
  <li>
     <a href="#" onclick="popWin('<?php echo $this->getGalleryUrl($_image) ?>', 'gallery', 'scrollbars=yes,width=200,height=200,resizable=yes');return false;">
     <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(68,68); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>"/>
     </a>
  </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Code lifted from:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/catalog/adding_lightbox_to_magento_v2

Note exactly the answer but obviously you can remove the foreach and simply supply the array's index if you know your only going to have one file.

Comment: I am working on your solution. I think I'll some dirty trick to make it work :). and for the record, you can not use `$this->getGalleryImages()` on **view.phtml** page, or do `$images = $this->getGalleryImages(); 
 $image2 = $images[1];` because, here array index is image id...

Comment: Thanks @b00mer,  I've solved my problem. I printed all images using `<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(68,68); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>" id="<?php echo 'image-'.$ctr ?>" style="display:none"/>` and displaying the images using jQuery

Comment: Only working version is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756103/magento-get-image-gallery-in-list-phtml?rq=1

Comment: what is `$this` in the context of your answer?