# display list of images for the same product in home page

Tags: web, magento-1.9

i am working on magento 1.9.2.4 
this the code that exist in my grid.phtml

```html
 <div class="box-images">
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
                    <img <?php if(isset($layzyload)): ?>class="owl-lazy"<?php endif; ?> <?php if(isset($layzyload)): ?>data-src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($widthImage, $heightImage); ?>"<?php else: ?>src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($widthImage, $heightImage); ?>"<?php endif; ?> alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
                </a>
                    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <div class="quickview"><a class="view-detail" <?php if(Mage::getStoreConfig('quickview/general/enabled')):?> id='fancybox<?php echo $_product->getId()?>'  href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('quickview/index/ajax',array('product_id'=>$_product->getId())); ?>"<?php else: ?> href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" <?php endif ?> title="<?php echo $this->__('Quick View') ?>"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a></div>
```

how do i change it to display all the image exists in this product

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento: Get Image Gallery in list.phtml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756103/magento-get-image-gallery-in-list-phtml)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $_gallery = $product->getMediaGalleryImages(); ?>
<?php foreach($_gallery as $_item): ?>
    <?php $_resized_image_url = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image', $_item->getFile())->resize($widthImage, $heightImage); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: You need to change it for your needs...

Place your <a> tag inside foreach loop. 
Then change your src attribute in <img /> tag to above variable $_resized_image_url.